# Script to periodically open a file at certain intervals?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I would like to write a script that would open a excel file periodically after certain intervals. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to open the Excel file on Ubuntu with the associated application (LibreOffice Calc, gNumeric, etc.)

The script would then look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  xdg-open /home/arp/Documents/periodic.xls
  sleep 600; # sleeps for 10 minutes or 600 seconds, adjust as desired
done
```

You can adjust the filename and the sleep time above.